# Проблема с переполнением элментов html css

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, scss

Проблема с переполнением данных, как это исправить?
[image: Что получается у меня]

*Разметка компонента ниже*

```
<div className="typed_food_item_container">
        <div className="main_menu_section_item_container">
            <img src={props.url} />
            <h3>{props.title}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

.typed_food_item_container {
width: fit-content;

.main_menu_section_item_container {
    display: flex;
    gap: 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    background-color: #ffd6bb;
    align-items: center;
    width: auto;

    h3 {
        color: #800000;
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
  }
 }
```

*Что в итоге нужно получить*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может дело в `width: fit-content;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот примерно так можно это сделать.

Первое - контейнер, который ограничивает контент.
Второе - наклон через `transform`.
Третье - `flex-shrink: 0`, который заставляет блоки игнорировать общую ширину контейнера и не ужиматься.

```css
.banner {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 50px 0;
  overflow-x: clip;
  height: 300px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  transform: skewX(335deg) skewY(5deg);
}

.typed_food_item_container {
  width: fit-content;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.typed_food_item_container .main_menu_section_item_container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #ffd6bb;
  align-items: center;
  width: auto;
}

.typed_food_item_container .main_menu_section_item_container h3 {
  color: #800000;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="typed_food_item_container">
      <div class="main_menu_section_item_container">
        <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
        />
        <h3>Большой текст</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="typed_food_item_container">
      <div class="main_menu_section_item_container">
        <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
        />
        <h3>Большой текст</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="typed_food_item_container">
      <div class="main_menu_section_item_container">
        <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
        />
        <h3>Вообще очень большйо текст</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="typed_food_item_container">
      <div class="main_menu_section_item_container">
        <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
        />
        <h3>Большой текст ещё больше</h3>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="typed_food_item_container">
      <div class="main_menu_section_item_container">
        <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
        />
        <h3>Невероятно большой текст вау</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!